# Facebook access permissions for app to browse page albums

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get the albums/photos of a page I manage using the Facebook PHP SDK. The page is not mine as such, I was given access to manage it from Facebook.

I have created a new app and selected "Website with Facebook Logon" which is already used for Facebook comments on my site.

I am using the Facebook PHP SDK located [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk).

When I query for the account's albums I am just getting `{ ["data"]=> array(0) { } }`
So it seems like some permissions issue, but I can't figure out how to fix it from facebook.

How do I give access to an app to browse the photo albums of a page? (Remember this is not my account, this is a page I manage, but I have manager access to it).

This is my code just in case I have something silly in my code. Thanks!

```
$fbconfig = array();
$fbconfig['appId'] = $appid;
$fbconfig['secret'] = $appsecret;
$facebook = new Facebook($fbconfig);
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();    

$albums = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'/albums','GET');
var_dump($albums);  //this outputs { ["data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/

Comment: I didn't quite get it. Where do I specify the 'manage_pages' in the PHP SDK? And how will facebook know that my app actually has permissions to access this specific page?

Comment: Read the doc CBRoe linked - it explains how a user grants your app permission to act on behalf of their pages

Comment: I did read it, the example uses javascript and expects the user to login. I dont want that, I want photos to show on my website even if the user does not have facebook. I just want my **app** to get the facebook albums and photos (serverside with Php not clientside with JS) and display them on the site without the user logging in or anything like that, not everyone has facebook!

Comment: _You_ have to login yourself (or another person that has manager rights for the page), and then get the page access token using your user access token. And if you use a long-lived user access token for that, then the page access token will not expire by default … apart from the detailed explanation in the docs, this has been discussed here multiple times already.

Comment: @CBroe, can you point me to where it is explained in the docs or where it was discussed here? I searched for hours and all examples seem to expect the user (my website visitor) to log in to facebook. I have manager rights for the page, where do I get the access token from? I mean which page do I have to go to, to do that? I couldnt find it anywhere. Thanks

Comment: !%$#, would you please start reading the document _carefully_ now? Wherever more knowledge about f.e. the login procedure is required, it links to other relevant parts of the docs.

Comment: @CBroe, I cant understand what comes from where. Thats the problem. Its not that I am not reading the doc, I have been browsing through the doc for hours before I gave up and asked for help. So pointing me back to the same thing is a bit pointless. I might be missing something obvious, these things happen...so if you don't want to answer in a bit detail fine maybe someone else will. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be:

- logged in Facebook with your own account by your app token
- Be An Administrator of the specific Facebook page
- And finally accept the right of "manage my page" requested by Facebook.

I understand that you are not the owner of the page but the real owner should put you as an Administrator on the spec of that page on Facebook...

Comment: Yes I am not the owner of the page, but I was given Manager rights. So just to make sure I understood things, I should do this only once. After that I can save the token to a file or database and reuse it? How do I know that it never expires and suddenly I start getting errors on my website?

Comment: When you agree with the permission of "manage my Facebook pages " you will keep that granted permission unless you change your Facebook password or you remove this granted permission in your personal app setting in Facebook.